# How to create an insert view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, triggers

I have two SQL Server instances on the same PC, a default and a named instance. I have to perform primary horizontal fragmentation. My database has 4 tables I have to fragment the tables on the basis of some conditions. I create a linked server and created a view that takes data from table from both instances and combines them into one view (database and tables on both instances are same/schema is same).

[image: View taking data from two instances]]

Query in view

[image: Query in View]

1. I want to write an insert view that inserts values in my first view, as first view returns data from two tables
2. I want to create a trigger for insert view when value is added in insert view trigger condition is checked and processed data in different tables as accordingly the condition let's say I want the data `where Semester > 5` in instance 1 (default instance) and `where Semester <= 5` must be stored in instance 2 (named instance).

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. And what is "Primary Horizontal Fragmentation"?

Comment: Primary Horizontal fragmentation is to fragment a table on multiple side base on Some Condition (Same DB, Same tables but different data as per condition e.g site 1 has data of customer from "New York", and site two has Data of customer from" London"

Comment: Well that explanation didn't help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: let me add things in this way thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use [INSTEAD OF](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx) triggers in your view. Given the fact that you want to process the data *inserted* to the view and given certain conditions, finally insert them in different tables [INSTEAD OF triggers in views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/def01zh2.aspx) should do it.